# Проблема с редактированием данных модуля drupal

Tags: php, drupal, хук

Здравствуйте уважаемые знатоки :)
Возникла проблема с написанием модуля под drupal7 при попытке редактирования формы в текстовые поля загружается значение "e" а не данные из базы данных.
Ниже приведен хук формы, и хук загрузки данных, можете подсказать в чем проблема или в какую сторону копать?

```
function who_form($form, &$form_state, $who = null)
{
$form['name'] = array(
    '#title'         => 'ФИО',
    '#type'          => 'textfield',
    '#default_value' => $who ? $who['name'] : '',
    '#required'      => true,
);

$form['category'] = array(
    '#title'         => 'Категория',
    '#type'          => 'select',
    '#options' => array(
     '0' => 'Государственники',
     '1' => 'Общественные деятели',
     '2' => 'Политики',
     '3' => 'Предприниматели',
     '4' => 'Руководители предприятий, организаций',
     '5' => 'Спортсмены',
     '6' => 'Ученые',
     '7' => 'Эксперты'),
    '#default_value' => $who ? $who['category'] : '0',
    '#required'      => true,
);

$form['sex'] = array(
    '#title'         => 'Пол',
    '#type' => 'radios',
    '#options' => array(
     '0' => 'Мужчина',
     '1' => 'Женщина'),
    '#default_value' => $who ? $who['sex'] : '0',
    '#required'      => true,
);


$form['born_date'] = array(
    '#title'  => 'Дата рождения',
    '#type' => 'date_popup',
    '#flavour' => 'inline',
    '#date_format' => 'd.m.Y',
    '#default_value' => $who ? $who['born_date'] : '0',
);


$form['about'] = array(
    '#title'         => 'Текст',
    '#type' => 'textarea',
    '#default_value' => $who ? $who['about'] : '',
    '#required'      => true,
);

$form['image'] = array(
    '#title'         => 'Фотография',
    '#type' => 'managed_file',
    '#progress_message' => 'Пожалуйста подождите',
    '#progress_indicator' => 'bar',
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#default_value' => $who ? $who['image'] : '',
    '#upload_location' => 'public://whoiswho/',
);

$form['submit'] = array(
    '#type'  => 'submit',
    '#value' => $who ? 'Сохранить' : 'Добавить',
);


if ($who) {
    $form['id'] = array(
        '#type'  => 'value',
        '#value' => $who['id'],
    );
}

return $form;
}

function who_load($id)
 {
$who = db_select('who', 'n')
    ->fields('n', array('id', 'category', 'name', 'sex', 'born_date', 'about', 'image'))
    ->condition('n.id', $id)
    ->execute()->fetchAssoc();

return $who;
}
```

Спасибо, вопрос решился, необходимо было в хуке меню всего-лишь изменить число элемента id, стояло 4, изменил на 3

```
$items['admin/content/who/%who/edit'] = array(
    'title'            => 'Редактировать',
    'page callback'    => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments'   => array('who_form', 3),
    'access arguments' => array('access administration pages'),
    'type'             => MENU_CALLBACK,
);
```

Comment: что выведет debug($who); ?

Comment: прошу прощение за задержку с ответом, дебаг выдает значение 'edit'

Comment: ну собственно вот и ответ на ваш вопрос